# How to draw a smooth line shape like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I draw a smooth line shape like this in Photoshop?
I have been trying using **Edit -> Transform Path -> Warp** but there I cannot control the shape.
[image]

Comment: You could use [Pen tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above line looks like it's been drawn freehand using the pencil tool, not the shape pen tool.

However, if you wanted to create this with the **Curvature Pen Tool** <kbd>P</kbd>, draw it and adjust the bezier curves as you go then stroke it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]